# general situation in web app?

Tags: database, database-design

I have 5 messages and below the messages there is a combobox for the user to post a new message in my browser. now the user posted a new message so as i dont want to refresh the entire page i have intiated an ajax call. so i am sending the message to the server via ajax and on the server my web app stores the message into the database. up to here i am clear.

now after saving it into the database without any additional hit to the database can i send the message back to the client?

what i am doing is, after storing the message into the database i am fetching it back again from the database and sending it to the client.

what is the right approach? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the technology stack you use. In JSF you would tell the table component that displays the previous messages to refresh itself when the new message is posted. This way you partially refresh the page elements that are affected by the AJAX call.

Comment: I am using simple jdbc. my question is whether i have to hit the database again to retrieve the stored message or is there any other way without hitting the database.